# How can I create a custom container view controller and swap certain parts depending on the users choice?

Tags: swift, view, containers, viewcontroller

So I posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29399665/what-is-the-best-way-to-develop-applications-using-the-auto-layout-in-xcode/29400011#29400011) and one of the answerers recommended using a custom container view controller.

What I want to do is have an app that works a bit like the one below:
[image: my basic app design]

Its a very bad diagram but what I am trying to make out is that there is a universal background, logo and border; the only thing that needs to change is the content part.

I have looked a lot online and have found nothing about custom container view controller view controllers for swift and how to swap the view controllers for the part that changes according to the user selection.

Would someone be able to explain if this is possible in swift? Maybe it is called something else and I am looking for the wrong thing. If it is possible how can this be done?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you want to show us what you tried so far. Suggestion: You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I appreciate your advice, and I will definitely take a look at those links for future question. For the issue I was having here though I explained I had researched it and found answers for objective-c but none for swift. I'm not sure what I should have been trying, that was why I asked the question.

Comment: @cross did you ever get this implemented!? Can you please share code if possible. I am attempting to do a slide menu and when the user makes selection it changes the view in the container view based on the choice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So if i am getting this right you want to present a ViewController within a another ViewController

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
var controller: UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewControllerStoryboard Name") as UIViewController
```

"ViewControllerStoryboard Name" is the storyboard name that can be set here

[image]

If you implement this right, the controller variable is going to be an instance of the 2nd menu choice.

So after that you have to add it to the current viewController.

```
view.addSubview(controller.view)
self.addChildViewController(controller)
```

To position it wherever you want , set the controller.view.frame before adding it to subview

Hope i helped and sorry for my english :)

Comment: Your english is great! :) Is it possible to add it and still be able to use auto layout? When I ran the code it overwrote everything on view one.

Comment: You want to use auto layout to the second view controller ?

Comment: Yes, is that still possible?

Comment: Yes there is a way i am thinking of but is a bit difficult. var controller: UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewControllerStoryboard Name") as YourViewControllerClassName  and then access the viewController views and add constraints programmatically

Comment: Ok, I see, so that make is quit complicated then. I think I will try just getting it positioned correctly first then I will try adding constraints programatically.

Comment: I my apps i try using UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds witch gives you current screen bounds , so you can position it correctly in each device